# Internet Connection Sharing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, connection-sharing, ics

A computer using Windows 7 is located in subnet 192.168.2.xxx and can connect to the Internet.

Another PC, also using Windows 7, is located in subnet 192.168.28.xxx but is offline.

How can I share the internet connection from the first one to the second one?

Both computers can see (i.e. ping) each other.

Answer (score 0):

1.Choose Start→Control Panel→Network and Internet. Click the Network and Sharing Center link.
The Network and Sharing Center opens.

2.Click Change Adapter Settings in the left column to open a Network Connections window.
Right-click and then click Properties on the shortcut menu to open the Properties for the connection.

3.Click the Sharing tab to display its contents

[image: ICS]

4.“Allow other network users to control or disable the shared Internet connection” option